# Can’t understand PHP/MySQL user registration functionality…

Tags: php, mysql

First, I’m not a programmer by nature, so I’m having trouble understand what’s happening in the below script (put together from a number of resources for a user registration form):

```
if (mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql))
{
    header("Location: registered.php");
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['error_reg']['email'] = "This email address is already registered.";
}
```

In this snippet, `$dbconnect` contains the MySQL connection script (using mysql) and `$sql` contains the sql table insertion code. Finally, the session info injects an error message into another script that’s under the form.

My question revolves around how the script knows if the email address exists in the table (it works, it really does) without having to select the row from the table. I’ve been seriously scratching my head about how it is work when I haven’t explicitly coded it to do so.

I hope that this isn’t vague enough… There’s really not much more to the script aside from some form field validation and capturing the form variables for insertion into the table (in `$sql`).

Thanks!

Comment: The `$sql` query would be relevant. If it's an INSERT with an existing DB table constraint, that would explain why it might (1) fail for duplicate addresses and (2) therefore got that plain `if` check to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question revolves around how the script knows if the email address exists in the table

It actually doesn't *know* in this case.  It *assumes*.  This is actually a pretty poor example of that described functionality.  This code is *assuming* that *any* failure of the database query means that the email address is already registered.

If there is *any* failure in executing the query (a syntax error, a database engine failure, anything), then `mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql)` is going to return `false`.  This code interprets that `false` value as the specific error message it displays.

Comment: Ah, ok! So, I’m assuming it’s working, when it isn’t.

That’s good info that I can run with. Thank you!

Comment: @TimSamoff: Well, it *might* be working.  In most cases it *is* working because it's probably not being tested against unexpected error conditions.  (Much in the same way that a car without brakes appears to be "working" if you don't test its ability to stop.)

Comment: Sorry, one more question, though… How is the error only appearing when an email is identical to  one in the DB?

Comment: @TimSamoff: That depends on what SQL query is being executed.  If the query is attempting to insert a record with a duplicate value in a table which has a unique constraint on that column, then the query will result in an error.  This code's assumption about that error, in that particular case, would coincidentally be correct.

Comment: Ok! That makes sense to me. I’ll bet that’s what’s happening.

Answer (score 1):

It can't possibly work. `mysqli_query()` has two possible return values: a statement handle/object if the query succeeded, or boolean false if the query outright failed.

A query which returns **NO** rows (e.g. `select .. where 1=0`) is **NOT** a failure. It's a perfectly valid query, which simply happens to have an empty result set.

A proper code sequence would be:

```
$result =  mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error($dbconnct));
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    return "not registered";
} else {
    return "already exists";
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I have researched — that’s why I was wondering why it was working at all.  I’m pretty sure that @David’s assessment is correct about what’s happening.

Comment: then, yeah, if it's doing an insert and checking for failure, that WOULD work, but since you never showed what's in `$sql`...

Comment: That’s because $sql isn’t checking for error: $sql = "INSERT INTO users (af_username, af_email, af_password, af_reg, af_token) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$email}', '{$password}', '{$reg}', '{$token}')"; But, since (and I did verify this) the DB columns are UNIQUE, it’s throwing back an error.